# Prolog: How to load a prolog program in Qprolog?

Tags: prolog

I'm running following command to load consumer.pl in command prompt. But it is not working.

| ?- consult('C:\QuProlog\examples\consumer.ql').

Comment: Inside an atom, the backslash character is used for *escape sequences*. Try instead the goal `consult('C:\\QuProlog\\examples\\consumer.ql').`.

Answer (score 0):

It is working with the following command now.
consult('consumer.ql').